How to apply style array to WebGL points layer (OpenLayers)
How can I apply an array of styles to a WebGL Points layer in OpenLayers? For example, if I use the following code to apply a circle and an icon, only the icon is visible - so is what I want to do even possible?
https://jsfiddle.net/Sidders/cbzrLjqd/
Example code:
const webGLstyle = {
  'circle-stroke-width': 2,
  'circle-stroke-color': '#333333',
  'circle-radius': 18,
  'circle-fill-color': "#FE6000",
  'circle-rotate-with-view': false,
  'circle-displacement': [0, 0],
  'circle-opacity': 1,
  'icon-src': 'https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/data/icon.png',
  'icon-width': 18,
  'icon-height': 28,
  'icon-color': 'lightyellow',
  'icon-rotate-with-view': false,
  'icon-displacement': [0, 9],
}

const webGLSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  url: 'https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/data/geojson/world-cities.geojson',
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  wrapX: true,
});

const myWebGLLayer = new ol.layer.WebGLPoints({
  source: webGLSource,
  style: webGLstyle
});


If it was possible you would need a flat style array, which does work with a standard vector layer
const webGLstyle = [
  {
    'circle-stroke-width': 2,
    'circle-stroke-color': '#333333',
    'circle-radius': 18,
    'circle-fill-color': "#FE6000",
    'circle-rotate-with-view': false,
    'circle-displacement': [0, 0],
    'circle-opacity': 1,
  },
  {
    'icon-src': 'https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/data/icon.png',
    'icon-width': 18,
    'icon-height': 28,
    'icon-color': 'lightyellow',
    'icon-rotate-with-view': false,
    'icon-displacement': [0, 9],
  },
];

const webGLSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  url: 'https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/data/geojson/world-cities.geojson',
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  wrapX: true,
});

const myWebGLLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: webGLSource,
  style: webGLstyle
});

I cannot make that work with WebGLPointsLayer, but it will work with a WebGLVector layer https://jsfiddle.net/Lk7udqjp/

Thanks Mike - yes the style array works fine with non-WebGL layers, but as I'm optimizing a map project, I was keen to utilize WebGL for some of my Vector/Points layers. Unfortunately, as you can see, recreating arrays (icons + shapes) didn't work. I really hope there is a way around it though other than having to use just images.

Quick solution would be to create two WebGL layers, one for each of the styles.

The style array will also work with a WebGL vector layer as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/webgl-vector-layer.html

Ah, sorry Mike! I missed that you made it work with a WebGL Vector Layer - thank you for following up - that's excellent!
